# Does Submit to Index on a page with new content update Content Keywords for the site?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot

Using Google Webmaster Tools I'm trying to update the `Content Keywords` of my site. I'm confused about the relationship between `Submit to Index` and `Content Keywords`

- Does `Fetch as Google` --> `Submit to Index` on a previously existing indexed page containing new content expidite updating the `Content Keywords` crawled by the *real* Google bot?
- Does `Submit to Index` only submit new URL's so that previously indexed URL's still point to the older cached version until Google crawls specifically for new content on its own?
- Does `Submit to Index` have anything to do with `Content Keywords` or crawling new content being a previously indexed page or never been indexed page?

Answer (score 1):

"Content Keywords" is what Googlebot found while crawling your site. That's not something you need to optimize for, it's also not what Google uses to determine the relevance of your site, it's just the words that were found. Unless the content there is completely irrelevant to your site (eg pharmaceuticals on a site about kittens), I wouldn't worry about what's shown there, and definitely not try to optimize a website for it.

Comment: Right but I'm not trying to optimize I'm trying to test to see if they are even getting scraped. I have a single page application that pulls in content dynamically via ajax and I am using rewrite rules to point web crawlers to my cached fully rendered pages. Does "submit to index" on a particular page force the crawler to re-crawl content on the page thus changing the content keywords for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch as Google it is just to tell Google Bots to crawl your page and submit to index appear on the later part. It is to get your website crawled rapidly otherwise Google does this indexing process automatically through its crawling spiders on regular basis. If your website or page URL is new you can click to submit to index and if its not then you do not need to ask Google to submit to index as there is no need of it. Google will do it automatically for you

Google index website only once and then keep on crawling after some time to update its status that either website page is still alive or not, is there any change in the page content if it is then update that in Google database.

Comment: So can you describe the relationship between `Content Keywords` and `Submit to Index`?